# how to copy contents of one array into another. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

i have a main array as

```
  arrayVariable = [1,2,3];
```

and i want another to variables to have the same content as above. If i do

```
anotherVariable = arrayVariable;
```

It will just reference that array and they wont be independent of each other.
I tried this solution, but it didnt work.

```
 var anotherVariable = arrayVariable.slice();
```

Edit: 
Another question, 
while passing array through a function, does it pass the array or is it passed by reference?

like

```
 var array = [];
 someFunction(array);

 function someFunction(array){};
```

Comment: .slice() should work. Can you give an example where it doesn't?

Comment: does a function pass the reference of the array? 
question updated.

Comment: it's an object, so by reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below code, look they are independent.

```js
arrayVariable = [1,2,3];
var anotherVariable = arrayVariable.slice(); // or .concat()

arrayVariable[0] = 50; // Hopefully it should not change the value of anotherVariable
alert(anotherVariable); // Look value of anotherVariable is not changed
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var aa = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var bb = [].concat(aa);//copy aa array to bb, they are now independent of each other.
```

hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a loop.

```
arrayvariable=[1,2,3];
for (var i=0;i<arrayvariable l.length;i++)
//while could also be used.
{ 

    anothervariable[i]=arrayvariable[i];
}
```